# Javascripts wont execute in Android webview

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

i have created a web app using query mobile and html5 and currently, none of my JS executes in the application.

JS is enabled on Android WebView as Jquery mobile can execute the JS for the library but does not work on an android device.

It works fine on the iOS simulator and on the web browser so i am wondering if there is some kind of hidden settings/implementation i need to handle for android?

here is the error i receive from an onClick event on a simple dialog html that is outputted using phone gap

```
07-15 09:25:00.621: E/Web Console(2992): Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadTrue is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/itemDetailCarHire.html:2
```

Here is the itemDetailCarHire html that launches the dialog that executes the onClick.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title></title>
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" />
<script src="src/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="src/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script>
<script src="src/script/itemDetailCarHire.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
  <script src="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="src/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="fields">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none" > <a href="" onclick="history.back(-1); return false;">Back</a>
    <h1>New Claim</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul class="ui-li" data-role="listview" id="claimProfileListView" data-inset="true"  data-scroll="true">

        <h3>Original Receipt:</h3>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <a href="uploadRecieptDialog.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Upload Reciept</a> </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="claimItemSummary.html" data-theme="b">Save Claim Item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When a user clicks the Original receipt component, it will correctly display the dialog called uploadRecieptDialog.html and the code for that is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title></title>
<link href="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" /> 
<script src="src/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="src/iscroll.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js"></script> 


</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page">

<div data-role="header"  data-theme="b"  data-position="fixed" >

        <h1>Upload Reciept</h1>

    </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <p>Click the button below to select and upload your Reciept</p>
    <h3><a onclick="uploadTrue();" data-role="button" data-theme="c" >upload Reciept</a></h3>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" >

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the updateDetailCarHire.JS

```
function uploadTrue(){
        alert("upload true");

        //load previous page
        history.back(-1); return false;
        alert("UPLOADED");

    }
```

A  simple JS as you can see that displays an alert message and goes back to previous screen. on iOS simulator and chrome/safari desktop web browser, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your Javascript isn't executing because cordova is having a problem with your history command.

Check here: [in Cordova 1.8.1 - Android history.back() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608926/in-cordova-1-8-1-android-history-back-not-working)

And possibly: [Why is javascript:history.go(-1); not working on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961376/why-is-javascripthistory-go-1-not-working-on-mobile-devices)

Try using `history.back();`

**EDIT:** I don't see updateDetailCarHire.JS being included on any of those HTML pages.

Comment: Its included in the itemDetailCarHire. check the headers of the code snippet i posted. i will try history.back();

Comment: How are you including it? document.write inside of itemDetailCarHire.js? Try putting that function directly on the page with the issue and see if it works. If so, it's not including it properly.